# Mouse click on Popup not navigating from page in flex application running on Mac 10.8 with Flash player 12 on Safari

Tags: macos, apache-flex, popup

I have scenario here : I am running my flex application in my Mac 10.8 machine with Flash player 12 on Safari browser . I have a registration form and it is validating various fields in it and when I hit Continue button it is not navigating to the next screen even if all the fields are validated. This registration form is a Popup. Can any body help me with this?